# How can I stream between computers with ffmpeg?

Tags: networking, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I'm using ffmpeg and ffplay to stream a raw H.264 video between two computers.
This is what the transmitting command line looks like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.h264 -f mpegts udp:10.0.2.101:1234
```

And this is the receiving side:

```
ffplay -f h264 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

The problem is that the the playback on the receiving side shows much worse quality than what I see when playing the source file on the sender side.
The network is actually a simulated network on my computer (two virtual machines) so there isn't any packet loss or anything.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Note that `-f h264 -f mpegts` is invalid. Just `-f mpegts` should suffice.

Answer (score 4):

You're re-encoding the video stream. Note that if you don't specify a video codec, ffmpeg will choose one for you – in your case, MPEG-2 with its default settings, which indeed will look quite bad.

If you plan on copying the bitstream, add the `-c:v copy` option to your sending command.